# Superset. Error while sending report by email

Tags: python, docker, apache-superset

Need help solving an issue with Superset (version 1.0.1) running on docker.

Sendings reports (dashboards) by email is configured. Small dashboards are sent fine.
But sending several report ends with this error:
`Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.`

```
[05/Oct/2021:16:00:06 +0300] "GET /static/assets/5d82d1b53c008164c101.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 308964 "http://192.168.90.132:8088/superset/dashboard/49/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0"
 Message: Failed to convert data to an object

 [2021-10-05 16:00:08,431: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Message: Failed to convert data to an object

 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,752: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
 , retrying in 0 seconds...
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,754: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
 , retrying in 0 seconds...
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,755: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
 , retrying in 0 seconds...
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,756: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
 , retrying in 0 seconds...
 Failed at generating thumbnail 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'screenshot'
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,758: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Failed at generating thumbnail 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'screenshot'
 Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/superset/utils/celery.py", line 50, in session_scope
     yield session
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 374, in run
     raise ex
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 371, in run
     session, self._model, self._scheduled_dttm
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 344, in run
     self._session, self._report_schedule, self._scheduled_dttm
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 261, in next
     raise ex
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 257, in next
     self.send()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 195, in send
     notification_content = self._get_notification_content()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 175, in _get_notification_content
     screenshot_data = self._get_screenshot()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 167, in _get_screenshot
     raise ReportScheduleScreenshotFailedError()
 superset.reports.commands.exceptions.ReportScheduleScreenshotFailedError: Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,775: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/superset/utils/celery.py", line 50, in session_scope
     yield session
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 374, in run
     raise ex
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 371, in run
     session, self._model, self._scheduled_dttm
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 344, in run
     self._session, self._report_schedule, self._scheduled_dttm
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 261, in next
     raise ex
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 257, in next
     self.send()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 195, in send
     notification_content = self._get_notification_content()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 175, in _get_notification_content
     screenshot_data = self._get_screenshot()
   File "/app/superset/reports/commands/execute.py", line 167, in _get_screenshot
     raise ReportScheduleScreenshotFailedError()
 superset.reports.commands.exceptions.ReportScheduleScreenshotFailedError: Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
 Report state: Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
 [2021-10-05 16:00:13,776: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-7] Report state: Report Schedule execution failed when generating a screenshot.
```